# How can I automatically protect blocks placed by a player in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I want to protect blocks per player rather than area, as is common. That is, when a block is placed by one player, no other player can mine nor use them (preferably unless they belong to some kind of "white list"). How can this be accomplished?

Comment: @Texenox - The primary question isn't asking for recommendations, so I'm sure this question is fine.

Comment: @BDawg Nope.  Asking for something that meets specific criteria meets our definition of a recommendation.  I'd recommend you read the links in the close text to understand how you might be able to reword these types of questions to be more acceptable.

Comment: @Frank I can see how a game recommendation type of question would be considered problematic in general. But, despite the word "recommend", this question doesn't seem to be attempting to elicit a subjective list of games/software. Rather, this is searching for any possible solution to their current problem within the context of a game.
Please see: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/1841/117893

Comment: @Frank To summarize: (From that link) "The acceptable goal of a question is that answers provide conclusions to the question on their own merits. They can have more than one answer as long as each good answer still provides a conclusion." I feel this qualifies based on that description.

Comment: @BDawg Thing is, though, we're still trying to meet an itemized list of criteria, specified by the user.  That's only helpful to the asker, and one of the things we strive here is for questions to help *many* readers, not just the asker.  There's also no objective way of voting on these answers; it turns into a popularity contest, rather than a judgement based on utility.  Those are two of the main reasons why we don't allow questions asking us to find items that meet specific criteria.

Comment: @Frank Thanks for taking the time to read my argument. I think I get that this is more about wording than anything. I'll try to edit the question

Comment: @BDawg, if in your revision, you remove specific details the author is requesting (eg. being able to tell if the user can modify the block based off a friends list), you are deviating from the authors intent. If you have interest in this question, and think you can word it to be more appropriate, ask it yourself. This seems the best resolution, as then it is *your* intent, and otherwise, I found no problem with your revision. I think you may have misread "white list" as asking for a list, where instead OP requests being able to compare against a "white list".

Comment: @Timelord64 Thanks, I actually just missed that part while trying to edit in a rush. Revised.

Comment: @PinkMonkeyBird - What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

One particular mod that I use on my server is Grief Prevention. It establishes a protection region for a player the moment they place their first chest, and then after that the region which is protected can be easily modified using the 'claimtool' (configurable, defaults to golden shovel). This also also can prevent players stepping into a protected claim (not by default).

This mod does require craftbukkit or spigot server, and using Cauldron is stable with forge mods.

To use this mod a player places a chest, the first of which will establish a 9 by 9 area that is protected to them alone.
To create or modify a claimed region you use a tool designated as the 'claimtool' in the configs. The mod provides useful directions from there.
Any area inside a claim is protected from other players breaking or placing blocks. Can't sleep, can't access chests etc.
If a player wishes it is possible to 'flag' a claim making it so not only can other players not modify the claim but also can not enter the claim. Literally, it bounces the players out and also prevents teleporting in.

The plugin also supports a number of options for sharing a protected area. For example, you can mark players as builders in you claim thus allowing them to break or place blocks, but not access inventories still.

I can't tell you how to administer a server, that's up to you, but this plugin is very useful and full of commands and options for that. It also supports multiple worlds.

A full list of commands can be found [here](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/grief-prevention/pages/command-and-permissions-reference/)

A tutorial

---

https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/griefprevention.1884/

http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/grief-prevention/

If you would like I can either find or make a video demonstrating this. 2 other servers which I play on also use it. It's second only to WorldGuard, which from your question wouldn't be as good as GriefPrevention.

Comment: question was tagged 'mods' so I assumed this would be appropriate as it does almost perfectly what questioner is askign.

Comment: Generally, it's a good idea to do more than just point at a mod that will do the trick.  Please specify *how* to use the suggested mod to do what the asker needs to.

Comment: @Frank I did mention the basics and really as much as most users are ever told on the server. I linked to the plugin so they would have more information. I wouldn't have enough room to explain the totality of the mod.

Comment: Your answer is very light on details on how to actually accomplish the task.  It's extremely heavy on alternate processes that might work, but you don't go into detail explaining how to use any of them to accomplish the task.

Comment: @Frank Well, I don't think I can add much more without just copy and pasting the authors own site....

Comment: @ydobonebi This is specifically what the op did not want - area-based protection.

Comment: @BDawg if configured correctly, it can actually accomplish what they want. Not that I recommend it. The amount of data storage used goes up with the increase per area protected per player. If you protect 1 block at a time that becomes a lot of data. However, this would allow to expand the area as/when more blocks are added. What the op is actually asking for is rather useless over all. When would you ever want to protect a single block, excluding inventory and interactive blocks?  This adds protections for this blocks as well however there's a better plugin just for that purpose.